# Rails: .require() without actually requiring it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I'm trying to use...

```
params.require(:subscriber).permit(:utm_source, :utm_medium, :utm_campaign, :utm_term, :utm_content)
```

The problem is there are rare occasions where I want to do:

`Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)`

And I don't care if all the values are empty... When I do this it raises `ActionController::ParameterMissing`

So what I need is a way to make `require()` "optional" but still use it for the benefit of restricting nested parameters and for security, so people can't add in `{admin: true}` and things like that...

The actual params hash looks like:

`{subscriber: {utm_source: 1, ...}`

I can't change that part because it's used in many other places of the app. It's just this one spot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `fetch` instead of `require`:

```
params.fetch(:subscriber).permit(:utm_source, :utm_medium, :utm_campaign, :utm_term, :utm_content)
```

Check the [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) for more information on *strong parameters*.

Comment: Thanks! What is a 'scalar'? I read these docs and I didn't quite understand a few bits

Comment: @Tallboy A _scalar_ could be described as **a variable that holds a single value**. For example, a number or a string are both scalar, but an array or hash are not. Check [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238033/what-does-it-mean-when-data-is-scalar) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: if subscriber might be empty do it like: params.fetch(:subscriber, {}).permit(...)